# Django queryset to get Top 3 users

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-queryset

I have a model:

```
class RnR(models.Model):
    emp_sent = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=122)
    badgename = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=122)
    message = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=122)
    emp_recvd = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=122)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Now the data in this table will be in the following way(example):

| emp_sent | badgename | message | emp_recvd | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tony | great job | good | Steve | 01/01/2020 |
| Tony | thank you | thanks | Nat | 04/02/2020 |
| Steve | great job | nice | Tony | 05/02/2020 |
| Steve | congo | nice | Nat | 05/04/2020 |
| Bruce | great job | nice work | Clint | 05/06/2020 |
| Nat | congo | nice | Bruce | 25/06/2020 |
| Steve | great job | nice | Nat | 05/07/2020 |
| Nat | thank you | nice work | Tony | 15/07/2020 |
| Steve | great job | nice | Bruce | 03/09/2020 |

Now I want to write a query-set that gives me the name of the Top 3 Senders (which in above example will be Steve, Nat and Tony, in that order) along with some other details like the badgename and the number of times sent and received. Here's how it will look:

(Note : The following table is just to make my question more clear, in my actual code I am going to display this information in a Bootstrap Carousel using Django context)

| Rank | Employee Name | Badgename | Sent | Received |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Steve | great job | 3 | 1 |
|  |  | congo | 1 | 0 |
|  |  | thank you | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | Nat | great job | 0 | 1 |
|  |  | congo | 1 | 1 |
|  |  | thank you | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | Tony | great job | 1 | 1 |
|  |  | congo | 0 | 0 |
|  |  | thank you | 1 | 1 |

I want do the same thing for Top 3 receivers too, but I will figure it out based on the answer for this.

Please tell me the query-set I will need or any other solutions if available. Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation) count and group by values as documented using [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#values)

So something in a line of

```
RnR.objects.all().values('emp_sent').annotate(total=Count('emp_sent')).order_by('-total')[:3]
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I just need to figure out how to get the count of every badge for each employee.